# Multiple python list using function

Tags: python

I have a multiple python list and each list should be converted to a string.

For example:

```
lista = ['a','b']
listb = ['c','d']
listc = ['e','f']
listd = ['g','h']
```

Output:

```
stra = "'a','b'"
strb = "'c','d'"
strc = "'e','f'"
strd = "'g','h'"
```

Comment: `stra = 'a','b'` is a tuple not string

Comment: Do you mean `stra = "'a','b'"`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Edited. Pretty sure this is what they meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert list to tuple, use tuple build-in function:

```
list = ['a', 'b']
t = tuple(list)
print t
>> ('a', 'b')
```

To make string that includes list's elements separated with some other string, use:

```
list = ['a', 'b']
s = ', '.join(list)
print s
>> a, b
```

Comment: I guess OP wants `"'a','b'"` as output.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [101]: lista=['a','b']
In [103]: ",".join(map(repr,lista))
Out[103]: "'a','b'"
```

Comment: This is nicer than Pawel's answer because it also works on lists with non-string members.

Comment: I always wondered, what interpreter uses that strange In/Out prompt?

Comment: @LukasGraf, you shouldn't wonder about such things - just ask :)

Comment: @DSM Thanks. I actually used IPython a couple times (never really liked it much), but never noticed that pattern.

Comment: @LukasGraf I am also a IPython newbie, I really like it's history feature(whole functions or compound statements can be accessed by up&down keys)

Answer (score 2):

```
"'"+"','".join(lista)+"'"
```

Where `lista` means a list of string elements. Probably it can be better written.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps? Assuming you left the quotes off the output

```
stra = str(lista)[1:-1]
strb = str(listb)[1:-1]
strc = str(listc)[1:-1]
strd = str(listd)[1:-1]
```

Comment: it worked..what does [1:-1] actuall do

Comment: This is probably not pythonic, but it gets my nod for being pragmatic (and for working on lists with non-string members).

Comment: It removes the first and last characters from the string. Try running it with those removed and you'll see why it's there.

Comment: This is very slightly different from the OP's examples, which don't have spaces between terms.

Comment: @DSM, True. This answer is not very flexible - you can't change the delimiter either. If the exact output is needed, Ashwini's answer is the way to go.